# How did several subscription on one observable

Tags: angular, observable

Sorry for my English. I have service that provide in main module. When did happen change `this.userSettings` object using `setSettings` method I want that all subscribers on `userSettingsObservable` were called. Subscription happens in different components through call `getSettingsObservable` method in this service.

```
    constructor() {
        this.userSettingsObservable =  new Observable((observer: Observer<UserSettings>) => {
            this.userSettingsObserver = observer;
        });
    }

    getSettingsObservable() {
        return this.userSettingsObservable;
    }

    setSettings(path: string) {
        this.userSettings = _.set(this.userSettings, path, value);
        this.userSettingsObserver.next(_.clone(this.userSettings));
    }
```

Examples of subscription on Observable in component:

```
ngOnInit() {        
    this.userSettingsService.getSettingsObservable().subscribe(
        (userSettings) => {
            this.userSettings = userSettings;
        }
    );
}
```

In my case subscribe calling only on last subscribed component.
How to make that subscribe calling in all components where I done subscribe?

Thanks!

P.S. You can see full code of service here: https://github.com/pakhuta/siarhei.pakhuta.angular2/blob/master/src/app/shared/user-settings.service.ts#L41

and subscription here: https://github.com/pakhuta/siarhei.pakhuta.angular2/blob/master/src/app/weather/weather.component.ts#L43

Comment: The problem is not clear. Is the issue when you userSettingObserver.next that not all subscribers get the value?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have several components where I done subscription. If I set breackpoint in Chrome developer console that only in one (last subscribed) component script execution stops.

Comment: Are you injecting or importing the service?

Comment: Also, where are you calling setSettings from?

Comment: Are you injecting or importing the service?


I don't know how it correctly called. In components I writing this:
constructor(private userSettingsService: UserSettingsService)

setSettings I calling in components, for example when user click on item in settings menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is a timing issue, and that the observable is completing before the other components have subscribed.

The easiest solution would to be to use a `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` instead of a regular observable.

```
constructor() {
        this.userSettingsObservable =  new ReplaySubject(1);//will only broadcast the last value when subscribed to
    }
```

And then :

```
this.userSettingsObservable.onNext(settings)
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it tomorrow

Comment: You were right. It's a great decision. I used:
this.userSettingsObservable =  new BehaviorSubject(this.userSettings);
this.userSettingsObservable.next(_.clone(this.userSettings));

Comment: Generally subjects are frowned upon, as they 'are little pockets of evil state' to paraphrase the author of rxjs. That being said, sometimes they are unavoidable.